# Navigation bar won't show when navigating between viewControllers

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an app with a chap integrated but the navigation bar won't show.

I am using this method to navigate from the Menu to the Conversations View Controller (which is embedded in a Navigation Controller and contains a TableView):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let _vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "conversacionesVC") as! ConversationsViewController
_vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(_vc, animated: true)
```

The property called "Shows Navigation Bar" is already checked but when the Conversations View Controller appears, it is missing the navigation bar.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the storyboard, but you say that `ConversationsViewController` is "embedded in a Navigation Controller". If that's true, you'd need to present the navigation controller - not `ConversationsViewController`. However, if `ConversationsViewController` itself is the navigation controller, it's probably a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `navigationController.pushViewController` method or present a `navigationController` not a `viewController` like below.

**Present UINavigationControlller:**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let _vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourNavigationController") as? UINavigationController
_vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(_vc, animated: true)
```

Note: Make sure your navigationController rootViewController is your presented viewController.

Answer (score 0):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
guard let _vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourNavigationController") as? ConversationsViewController else{return}

vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
let navVc = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: _vc)
self.present(navVc, animated: true)
```